# Adding IPv6 breaks StackExchange

Tags: ipv6

I added IPv6 on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS laptop by adding an OpenVPN tunnel to my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server that has IPv6.  I am using masquerading on both IPv6 and IPv4.

Using StackExchange used to have a regularly updated count of updated/new questions where I could click and have them loaded without reloading the whole page.  Now it is no longer there.

I do not see any AAAA records for a few StackExchange hosts I checked.

```
laptop2/stackex /home/stackex 1> a unix.stackexchange.com
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 in  a   104.16.119.182
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 in  a   104.16.117.182
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 in  a   104.16.118.182
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 in  a   104.16.115.182
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 in  a   104.16.116.182
laptop2/stackex /home/stackex 2> aaaa unix.stackexchange.com
laptop2/stackex /home/stackex 3> aaaa linuxhomepage.com
linuxhomepage.com.  21600   in  aaaa    2a02:348:61:5d75::a
linuxhomepage.com.  21600   in  aaaa    2a02:348:61:5d75::b
linuxhomepage.com.  21600   in  aaaa    2a02:348:61:5d75::c
linuxhomepage.com.  21600   in  aaaa    2a02:348:61:5d75::d
linuxhomepage.com.  21600   in  aaaa    2a02:348:61:5d75::e
linuxhomepage.com.  21600   in  aaaa    2a02:348:61:5d75::f
laptop2/stackex /home/stackex 4>
```

**Any idea what I broke?**

Yes, this seems strange, so I am wondering.

Comment: Would you add more details, masquerading/routing/vpn rules?

Answer (score 1):

All those sites that dont show ipv6 address will have this problem.
May be stack-exchange is not running on IPV6:

```
root@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~# host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 216.58.210.68
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:811::2004

root@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~# host www.ncp.edu.pk
www.ncp.edu.pk has address 111.68.96.165
www.ncp.edu.pk has IPv6 address 2400:fc00:854a:aaaa:700d:d110:e593:8d00

root@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~# host stackexchange.com
stackexchange.com has address 104.16.116.182
stackexchange.com has address 104.16.119.182
stackexchange.com has address 104.16.118.182
stackexchange.com has address 104.16.115.182
stackexchange.com has address 104.16.117.182
```

why it is not showing any ipv6 address.

Comment: Excellent point, modding you up.

Comment: i had faced this problem with github.com

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.